# Adding Drupal field "subtitle" to page template

Tags: entities

I have created a Content Type called "Happy Days". I have created a field in that called "subtitle".

In my template "page--happy-days.tpl.php", I want the field "subtitle" to show wrapped in an  tag. I attempted:

```
<h2><?php print render($content['field_subtitle']); ?></h2>
```

but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you cleared the cache. Your issue is [page--content-type.tpl.php override not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/1124036). Try to suggest theme hook in `THEME_preprocess_node`.

Furthermore you need to theme nodes of `Happy Day` content type, so you must use `node--CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php`. For more information visit [Theming nodes by content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565) page.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are using **render()** function. This function provides output with already assigned style. So that's why you can't see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) module to change wrapping tags for fields

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time you display the field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can check specific path of field using devel 
using dsm(*********['field_subtitle']); or check this link 
https://www.drupal.org/node/316688